# Can't seem to end loop in wordpress page template

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts

Full disclosure, I'm a PHP noob.
I'm having an issue with a page template I'm trying to build for my Wordpress site. The idea is to show every post from today, and exclude all others.

Someone helped me build some code, but I have a new issue - only the oldest post from today is showing! I tested with three posts spaced apart by a few minutes, and only the first one shows up.

Any help appreciated.

Full code follows.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Home Page
 * The template for displaying all of today's posts on home page.
 *
 * This is the template that displays only today's posts.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
 * other "pages" on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day' => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>


<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

    <?php
    // Start the loop.
    if ($query->have_posts() )
        echo'<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        // Include the page content template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();

        /* Restore Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        else : // no posts found. 
        ;

    endif ;
    ?>

    </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: from admin set posts per page to -1

Comment: I assume you mean from the Reading Settings. It doesn't let me use anything less than 0.

Comment: Then make it zero, the prob you are facing is actually for paging

Comment: Whoops, I meant less than 1. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out! It turns out that

```
echo '<li>' . get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ) . '</li>';
```

should have been inside of the while loop.

That's why it was only showing me the first one. No paging issues.

After that the only issue was the fact that links were not working for some reason - so I got rid of the call for 'page' in the get_template_part function. It's all working great now!

Anyway, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year' => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day' => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: No change :/
Maybe some of my other settings make a difference?
Theme: Twenty-Fifteen
I've set a specific Home page as my front page so I can apply a custom page template php file.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @dovid , which one is your home page ? index.php ? or any static page  can you check ?

Comment: Right now, I'm thinking that my problem is that there's no pointer into the array to increment the post forward.

Comment: @Mickey I've set the front page of the site to a new page I called "Home," and that is running from a custom template I'm building called hompepage.php.